# import python module in a shared library from memory

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible to load a python module from memory rather than from a file?

This is on Linux.
The module is a shared library written in C.
The shared library is not saved as a file on the disk. I only have the contents of the file in memory and I can't write it to a temporary file on the disk.

Comment: Considering that anything on disk has to be loaded into memory before it can be used, the answer is more than likely yes

Comment: Is your tag correct? How is the module loaded?

Comment: The tag is correct. I'm reading the module from a zip file. I can read from the disk but not write.

Comment: The problem is that the import is using [`dlopen()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) which takes a path in the file system. So unless you can find some way to store the file in the file system I think that the answer to your question is negative.